# Combine big list into a dict

Tags: python

Imagine I have this list:

```
list = [['Artur', 23, 'USA'], ['Maria', 22, 'Brazil'], ['Felix', 19, 'Mexico']]
```

How to convert it to a dict, like this:

```
dict = {'Name': 'Artur', 'Age': 23, 'Country': 'USA' ... }
```

I used this way but only convert the first:

```
dict = dict(zip(['name', 'value', 'status', 'time'], list))
```

**Edit:**

I created a list of dict and worked.

```
list_dict = [dict(zip(['name', 'value', 'status', 'time'], values)) for values in data]
```

Comment: You probably want a list of dicts.

Comment: dictionary cannot have the same keys.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?
A list of dicts can be had like this:

```
list = [['Artur', 23, 'USA'], ['Maria', 22, 'Brazil'], ['Felix', 19, 'Mexico']]

result = []
for e in list:
    result.append({
        'Name': e[0],
        'Age': e[1],
        'Country': e[2]
    })

print(result)
```

Result:

```
[{'Name': 'Artur', 'Age': 23, 'Country': 'USA'}, {'Name': 'Maria', 'Age': 22, 'Country': 'Brazil'}, {'Name': 'Felix', 'Age': 19, 'Country': 'Mexico'}]
```

Or a dict of lists, like this:

```
result = {
    'Name': [],
    'Age': [],
    'Country': []
}
for e in list:
    result['Name'].append(e[0])
    result['Age'].append(e[1])
    result['Country'].append(e[2])
print(result)
```

Result:

```
{'Name': ['Artur', 'Maria', 'Felix'], 'Age': [23, 22, 19], 'Country': ['USA', 'Brazil', 'Mexico']}
```

(not sure what you'd use that for).

Did you want something different?  If you really want a single dictionary at the top level, you'll have to describe better what that would look like.

With a list like this, you could also build indexes that would allow you to look up an entry in the list by name, age, or country.  Since all of those will generally not be unique, you'd have to deal with that, but that's not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your usecase is so I will assume you want to create a list of dictionaries. However, if you were to load them into a DataFrame, it will be easier to keep it as the current list.

For example:

```
lst = [['Artur', 23, 'USA'], ['Maria', 22, 'Brazil'], ['Felix', 19, 'Mexico']]
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data = lst, columns = (['name','value','country']))
```

will convert the above list into a DataFrame.

```
    name  value country
0  Artur     23     USA
1  Maria     22  Brazil
2  Felix     19  Mexico
```

If you want to stay with lists and dictionaries, then getting all the names will require you to traverse through the full list.

If you do want to get all names under key = `'name'`, all values under key = `'value'`, and all countries under key = `'country'`, then you can try something like this.

```
from collections import defaultdict
dct = defaultdict(list)

for name,value,country in lst:
     dct['name'].append(name)
     dct['value'].append(value)
     dct['country'].append(country)

dct = dict(dct)
print (dct)
```

This will convert the list into a dictionary as follows:

```
{'name': ['Artur', 'Maria', 'Felix'], 'value': [23, 22, 19], 'country': ['USA', 'Brazil', 'Mexico']}
```